# CakePHP update a child model from parent

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am currently struggling to get an associated model to update with CakePHP 2.3. I want the parent model to be inactive, and the child model record to be inactive.  I have the following method in my Company Model, which just updates the parent model (and not the child). What is the best way to achieve this? I tried moving the method to the child object, but it makes no difference.

```
class Company extends AppModel {
     public $hasMany = array(
        'CompaniesUser' => array(
            'className' => 'CompaniesUser'
        )
    );


function updateToInactive( $companyId ){
            $data = array(
                    array(
                    'Company' => array(
                      'id' =>$companyId, 
                      'active' => 0, 
                      'payment_active'=> 0
                    ),
                    'CompaniesUser' => array(
                      'company_id' =>$companyId, 
                      'active' => 0)
                    )
            );
            $this->saveAll($data);
}
```

}

My CompaniesUser Model looks like this:( belongs to Company )

```
class CompaniesUser extends AppModel {
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Company' => array(
        'className' => 'Company',
        'foreignKey' => 'company_id'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$data` array looks wrong to me for a `hasMany` relationship. It should look something more like this:-

```
$data = array(
  'Company' => array(
    'id' =>$companyId, 
    'active' => 0, 
    'payment_active'=> 0
  ),
  'CompaniesUser' => array(
    array(
      'company_id' =>$companyId, 
      'active' => 0
    )
  )
);
$this->saveAssociated($data);
```

It is also better to use `saveAssociated()` than `saveAll()` as you are saving associated data.

**Update**

The above will not update the existing CompaniesUsers unless you pass the primary keys with the save data. You could save the company first then use `updateAll()` to update the users data for the related company. If you use `updateAll()` you need to remember to [escape the values being saved](http://andy-carter.com/blog/use-cakephp-2-s-updateall-method-with-caution):-

```
// Update company
$data = array(
    'id' =>$companyId, 
    'active' => 0, 
    'payment_active'=> 0
);
$this->save($data);

// Update company users
$this->CompaniesUser->updateAll(
    array('CompaniesUser.active' => '"0"'),
    array('CompaniesUser.company_id' => '"' . $companyId . '"')
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.. results in one update in the parent model, and an insert in the child model.  (CompaniesUser)

Comment: You need to pass the `CompaniesUser` primary key if you want it to update rather than insert.

Comment: So if I wanted to update all children rows with a parent row id of $companyId do I perform something different?